# How to turn characters into numeric without generating NAs

Tags: r, character, sweave

I'm using [R](http://www.r-project.org/) and [Sweave](http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/~leisch/Sweave/) to detect and display inconsistencies in a large data collection (several hundred variables and several thousand observations). These inconsistency checks include either logical checks, checks for sums etc. The data set provides the possibility to insert values, but also predefined codes. Thus, all cells in the data set are of type character, which troubles me when I'm testing for sums or e.g. "larger than" conditions. When I convert the characters into numeric, the predefined codes are converted to NAs, which also troubles me when I'm testing conditions on these codes, which is also mandatory. A small example:

```
 > a <- c(1,4,3,4,"m","s")
 > b <- c(1,33,1,"m",44,1)
 > c <- cbind(a,b)
 > a>b
 [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

You see, e.g. 4>33 shouldn't be detected as TRUE of course. Is there a way to convert charaters to numeric without turning the codes in my data set into NA, so that I can also test conditions on them?

Thanks in advance for your help!

(edited for readability, making each line of code using its own single line)

Comment: They shouldn't actually be compared. What I do is to assure a certain data quality by checking incoming data. When e.g. a is the lowest level of something and b the highest level of something, then I should detect that the third observation cannot be true. Of course, I cannot compare the characters with numbers. But in another step, I might control that a cell only includes either a number, or m, s or a. Nothing else can be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix numerics and characters in one vector. For the example you could use ordered factors:

```
a <- c(1,4,3,4,"m","s")
class(a)
#[1] "character"
b <- c(1,33,1,"m",44,1)

library(gtools)
levels <- mixedsort(union(a, b))
levels[6:7] <- levels[7:6]
#[1] "1"  "3"  "4"  "33" "44" "s"  "m"

a <- factor(a, levels=levels, ordered=TRUE)
b <- factor(b, levels=levels, ordered=TRUE)

a > b
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

But that doesn't help with the sum. In fact, what is`"s" + 1` supposed to result in?

Comment: Thanks for your fast response Roland. With my control file, I have e.g. four breakdowns which result in a total. Three breakdowns might include numbers, let's say 1, 2 and 3. The fourth might include "s" which says that the number for this breakdown is included in another breakdown. When the total is six, the condition for sum is fullfilled and shouldn't be detected as error. Thus, the "s" should be counted as 0 or ignored. In another observation, I might have 4 numbers and I want to control if the sum of them is equal to the total, and so on.Since Excel can solve this, I thought R might too.

Comment: You need to make your question much more specific with a full representative example including the expected result. The question in the title can only be answered with "not possible", but that doesn't mean that you can't do what you need to do (as I've tried to demonstrate). R can certainly do everything that Excel can do.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys, I solved the problem by creating a second data set, where I transformed characters to numbers. Now I test logical consistency of codes and consistency of sums etc. separately. Now another problem turned up: The way I detect mistakes in sums is working only for cases where no code and after transformation NA is present. If a cell contains NA the sum of it is not tested. But this actually should be the case. A short example:

```
> name <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
> a <- c(1,4,3,4,"m","s")
> b <- c(1,33,1,"m",44,1)
> c <- c(1,1,1,1,1,"x")
> sum <- c(3,40,5,5,45,2)
> d<- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c,sum), stringsAsFactors=F)
> d2 <- as.data.frame(sapply(d,as.numeric))
Warnmeldungen:
1: In lapply(X, FUN, ...) : NAs durch Umwandlung erzeugt
2: In lapply(X, FUN, ...) : NAs durch Umwandlung erzeugt
3: In lapply(X, FUN, ...) : NAs durch Umwandlung erzeugt
> d1 <- cbind(name,d2)
> d1
  name  a  b  c sum
1    a  1  1  1   3
2    b  4 33  1  40
3    c  3  1  1   5
4    d  4 NA  1   5
5    e NA 44  1  45
6    f NA  1 NA   2
> test_total <- which((d1[,2]+d1[,3]+d1[,4])!=d1[,5])
> total_wrong <- d1$name[test_total]
> total_wrong
[1] b
```

As you can see, b is detected as wrong, which is right. but in my data set, also f should be detected as wrong. Do you have any idea where I can add a condition to count NA as 0?